# Ionic 3: Return on If inside function subscribe()

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

So I added an if conditional into my subscribe() and I used return; to break if it's satisfied however it's not breaking the big function and only breaks the subscribe() and it goes through to the navCtrl.push line, what can I do?

```js
grabInfo(){
    this.ServiceProvider.grabRAW(this.email).subscribe(data => {
        this.infoList = data.data;
        if (this.infoList == null){
          loader.dismiss();
          toast.present();
          return;}
        //console.log(this.infoList);
        this.navCtrl.push(ResultPage,{infoList: this.infoList});
      }
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed, there ya go if you ever meet this

```js
  grabInfo(){

    this.ServiceProvider.grabRAW(this.email).subscribe(data => {
        this.infoList = data.data;
        if (typeof this.infoList[0] != 'undefined'){
          this.navCtrl.push(ResultPage,{infoList: this.infoList})}
        else{
          loader.dismiss();
          toast.present();
        }
      }
    );
  }
```